# Advice for NSWindow display

Tags: macos, cocoa, nswindow

In common cases, the application will layout with TITLE at top and ViewController at bottom. However, I would like to make my application with left-right display.

With split view controller, the title will still be at TOP of all views. Any idea how to fix it? or should I create 2 NSWindows? BTW, my UI designed using storyboards.

[image]

Here (Message) is what I want to display.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While NSWindow is selected, in attribute inspector, check Unified Title and Toolbar and Full size content view. This will make window with just show controls on it. You can add NSSplitView after that to get that appearance.

Remove any NSToolBar if there.

Also alter NSWindow property:

```
self.window.titleVisibility = NSWindowTitleHidden;
self.window.titlebarAppearsTransparent = YES;
self.window.backgroundColor = [NSColor whiteColor];
```